# Having trouble styling an SVG with a gradient

Tags: html, css, svg, leaflet

I have a live map of vehicle locations. I'm using an SVG to give the markers a top-view shape. Each vehicle has a different livery: this is either a solid colour or a gradient. Currently, I apply the livery's CSS like this:

```
<svg style="background:linear-gradient(60deg,#0000 72%,#e41e26 20%),linear-gradient(60deg,#6f0f16 28%,#0000 28%),linear-gradient(to top,#e41e26 15%,#0000 15%),linear-gradient(60deg,#0000 31%, #ffea03 31%, #ffea03 39%,#0000 39%),#e41e26" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 150.25">
```

In this case, the livery is the linear gradient.

The problem is, because I have defined it within the `<svg>` tag, it is applied to the entire svg rather than inside the vehicle itself. Below is an example of an entire svg code (including its parents):

```
<button class="marker-wrapper marker-wrapper--vehicle" style="transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); outline-style: none;">
   <div class="live-vehicle-marker live-vehicle-marker--bearing live-vehicle-marker--bus">
      <div class="live-vehicle-marker__inner">
         <div class="live-vehicle-marker__vehicle" style="transform: rotate(257deg);">
         <svg style="background:linear-gradient(60deg,#0000 72%,#e41e26 20%),linear-gradient(60deg,#6f0f16 28%,#0000 28%),linear-gradient(to top,#e41e26 15%,#0000 15%),linear-gradient(60deg,#0000 31%, #ffea03 31%, #ffea03 39%,#0000 39%),#e41e26" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 150.25">
               
               <g class="map-bus-marker-1">
               <g data-name="Layer 2">
                  <g data-name="Layer 1">
                     <g>
                        <rect data-name="Bounding box" class="map-bus-marker-2" y="0.25" width="60" height="150"></rect>
                        <path data-name="Arrow" class="map-bus-marker-arrow" d="M22.5,14.25l7.5-10,7.5,10a23.3,23.3,0,0,0-15,0Z"></path>
                     </g>
                     
                     <g data-name="Vehicle detail">
                        <g data-name="Drop shadow" class="map-bus-marker-5">
                           <g data-name="shadow 2" class="map-bus-marker-6">
                              <path d="M30,4.25l7.5,10a23.3,23.3,0,0,0-15,0l7.5-10m0,14a20,20,0,0,1,13.23,5l2.05,1.81A11,11,0,0,1,49,33.31v6.94h1a5,5,0,0,1,5,5v1a2,2,0,0,1-2,2H49V138a4,4,0,0,1-4,4l-.47,0L30,140.26,15.47,142,15,142a4,4,0,0,1-4-4V48.25H7a2,2,0,0,1-2-2v-1a5,5,0,0,1,5-5h1V33.31a11,11,0,0,1,3.72-8.25l2-1.81a20,20,0,0,1,13.23-5M30,0a4.24,4.24,0,0,0-3.4,1.7l-7.5,10A4.25,4.25,0,0,0,19,16.64a24.39,24.39,0,0,0-5,3.43l-2,1.8A15.25,15.25,0,0,0,6.75,33.31v3.28a9.27,9.27,0,0,0-6,8.66v1a6.27,6.27,0,0,0,6,6.25V138A8.26,8.26,0,0,0,15,146.25a7.73,7.73,0,0,0,1-.06l14-1.65,14,1.65a7.73,7.73,0,0,0,1,.06A8.26,8.26,0,0,0,53.25,138V52.5a6.27,6.27,0,0,0,6-6.25v-1a9.27,9.27,0,0,0-6-8.66V33.31a15.25,15.25,0,0,0-5.16-11.44l-2-1.8a24.39,24.39,0,0,0-5-3.43,4.25,4.25,0,0,0-.11-4.94l-7.5-10A4.24,4.24,0,0,0,30,0Z"> </path>
                           </g>
                           <g data-name="shadow 4" class="map-bus-marker-7">
                              <path d="M30,4.25l7.5,10a23.3,23.3,0,0,0-15,0l7.5-10m0,14a20,20,0,0,1,13.23,5l2.05,1.81A11,11,0,0,1,49,33.31v6.94h1a5,5,0,0,1,5,5v1a2,2,0,0,1-2,2H49V138a4,4,0,0,1-4,4l-.47,0L30,140.26,15.47,142,15,142a4,4,0,0,1-4-4V48.25H7a2,2,0,0,1-2-2v-1a5,5,0,0,1,5-5h1V33.31a11,11,0,0,1,3.72-8.25l2-1.81a20,20,0,0,1,13.23-5M30,1.5a2.75,2.75,0,0,0-2.2,1.1l-7.5,10a2.76,2.76,0,0,0,0,3.26A2.7,2.7,0,0,0,22,17a22.91,22.91,0,0,0-7,4.24l-2,1.8A13.79,13.79,0,0,0,8.25,33.31V37.7a7.76,7.76,0,0,0-6,7.55v1A4.75,4.75,0,0,0,7,51H8.25v87A6.76,6.76,0,0,0,15,144.75a5.24,5.24,0,0,0,.79-.05L30,143l14.21,1.67a5.24,5.24,0,0,0,.79.05A6.76,6.76,0,0,0,51.75,138V51H53a4.75,4.75,0,0,0,4.75-4.75v-1a7.76,7.76,0,0,0-6-7.55V33.31A13.79,13.79,0,0,0,47.1,23l-2.05-1.8A22.91,22.91,0,0,0,38,17a2.7,2.7,0,0,0,1.73-1.09,2.76,2.76,0,0,0,0-3.26l-7.5-10A2.75,2.75,0,0,0,30,1.5Z"> </path>
                           </g>
                           <g data-name="shadow 7" class="map-bus-marker-8">
                              <path d="M30,4.25l7.5,10a23.3,23.3,0,0,0-15,0l7.5-10m0,14a20,20,0,0,1,13.23,5l2.05,1.81A11,11,0,0,1,49,33.31v6.94h1a5,5,0,0,1,5,5v1a2,2,0,0,1-2,2H49V138a4,4,0,0,1-4,4l-.47,0L30,140.26,15.47,142,15,142a4,4,0,0,1-4-4V48.25H7a2,2,0,0,1-2-2v-1a5,5,0,0,1,5-5h1V33.31a11,11,0,0,1,3.72-8.25l2-1.81a20,20,0,0,1,13.23-5M30,3a1.27,1.27,0,0,0-1,.5l-7.5,10a1.25,1.25,0,0,0,1,2,1.39,1.39,0,0,0,.4-.06,22,22,0,0,1,14.2,0,1.39,1.39,0,0,0,.4.06,1.25,1.25,0,0,0,1-2L31,3.5A1.27,1.27,0,0,0,30,3Zm0,14a21.22,21.22,0,0,0-14.06,5.32l-2,1.8a12.23,12.23,0,0,0-4.15,9.19V39a6.27,6.27,0,0,0-6,6.25v1A3.26,3.26,0,0,0,7,49.5H9.75V138A5.25,5.25,0,0,0,15,143.25c.2,0,.41,0,.61,0L30,141.52l14.39,1.69a4.17,4.17,0,0,0,.61,0A5.25,5.25,0,0,0,50.25,138V49.5H53a3.26,3.26,0,0,0,3.25-3.25v-1a6.27,6.27,0,0,0-6-6.25V33.31a12.23,12.23,0,0,0-4.15-9.19l-2-1.8A21.22,21.22,0,0,0,30,17Z"> </path>
                           </g>
                           <g data-name="shadow 10" class="map-bus-marker-9">
                              <path d="M30,4.25l7.5,10a23.3,23.3,0,0,0-15,0l7.5-10m0,14a20,20,0,0,1,13.23,5l2.05,1.81A11,11,0,0,1,49,33.31v6.94h1a5,5,0,0,1,5,5v1a2,2,0,0,1-2,2H49V138a4,4,0,0,1-4,4l-.47,0L30,140.26,15.47,142,15,142a4,4,0,0,1-4-4V48.25H7a2,2,0,0,1-2-2v-1a5,5,0,0,1,5-5h1V33.31a11,11,0,0,1,3.72-8.25l2-1.81a20,20,0,0,1,13.23-5m0-14.5a.48.48,0,0,0-.4.2L22.1,14a.51.51,0,0,0,0,.59.49.49,0,0,0,.41.21.45.45,0,0,0,.16,0,22.87,22.87,0,0,1,14.68,0,.45.45,0,0,0,.16,0,.49.49,0,0,0,.41-.21.51.51,0,0,0,0-.59L30.4,4a.48.48,0,0,0-.4-.2Zm0,14a20.49,20.49,0,0,0-13.57,5.13l-2,1.8a11.52,11.52,0,0,0-3.89,8.63v6.44H10a5.51,5.51,0,0,0-5.5,5.5v1A2.5,2.5,0,0,0,7,48.75h3.5V138a4.51,4.51,0,0,0,4.5,4.5l.53,0L30,140.77l14.47,1.7.53,0a4.51,4.51,0,0,0,4.5-4.5V48.75H53a2.5,2.5,0,0,0,2.5-2.5v-1a5.51,5.51,0,0,0-5.5-5.5h-.5V33.31a11.52,11.52,0,0,0-3.89-8.63l-2-1.8A20.49,20.49,0,0,0,30,17.75Z"> </path>
                           </g>
                        </g>
                        <g>
                           <path class="map-bus-marker-10" d="M30,20.25a18,18,0,0,1,11.91,4.5l2,1.81a9,9,0,0,1,3,6.75v8.94h3a3,3,0,0,1,3,3v1H47V138a2,2,0,0,1-2,2h-.23L30,138.25,15.23,140H15a2,2,0,0,1-2-2V46.25H7v-1a3,3,0,0,1,3-3h3V33.31a9,9,0,0,1,3.05-6.75l2-1.81A18,18,0,0,1,30,20.25m0-2a20,20,0,0,0-13.23,5l-2,1.81A11,11,0,0,0,11,33.31v6.94H10a5,5,0,0,0-5,5v1a2,2,0,0,0,2,2h4V138a4,4,0,0,0,4,4l.47,0L30,140.26,44.53,142l.47,0a4,4,0,0,0,4-4V48.25h4a2,2,0,0,0,2-2v-1a5,5,0,0,0-5-5H49V33.31a11,11,0,0,0-3.72-8.25l-2.05-1.81a20,20,0,0,0-13.23-5Z"> </path>
                        </g>
                        <g data-name="Internal shading">
                           <g class="map-bus-marker-11">
                              <path d="M30,32.25A15,15,0,0,1,39.93,36l2,1.81a6,6,0,0,1,2,4.5v94.57l-13.65-1.61-.35,0-.35,0L16,136.88V42.31a6,6,0,0,1,2-4.5l2-1.81A15,15,0,0,1,30,32.25m0-3a18,18,0,0,0-11.91,4.5l-2,1.81A9,9,0,0,0,13,42.31V138a2,2,0,0,0,2,2h.23L30,138.25,44.77,140H45a2,2,0,0,0,2-2V42.31a9,9,0,0,0-3-6.75l-2-1.81A18,18,0,0,0,30,29.25Z"> </path>
                           </g>
                           <g>
                              <path data-name="windscreen" class="map-bus-marker-3" d="M44,26.56l-2-1.81a18,18,0,0,0-23.82,0l-2,1.81A9,9,0,0,0,13,33.31v9a9,9,0,0,1,3.05-6.75l2-1.81a18,18,0,0,1,23.82,0l2,1.81a9,9,0,0,1,3,6.75v-9A9,9,0,0,0,44,26.56Z"> </path>
                              <path class="map-bus-marker-13" d="M18.09,24.75l-2,1.81A9,9,0,0,0,13,33.31v9a9,9,0,0,1,3.05-6.75l2-1.81A18,18,0,0,1,30,29.25v-9A18,18,0,0,0,18.09,24.75Z"> </path>
                           </g>
                           <rect data-name="Bounding box" class="map-bus-marker-2" y="0.25" width="60" height="150"></rect>
                        </g>
                     </g>
                  </g>
               </g>
            </g></svg>
         </div>
         <div class="live-vehicle-marker__name">75</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</button>
```

[The output of the above SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO7bL.png)

I need the css to be applied only to the interior of the vehicle, if that makes sense.

Having the css within the  tag applies the css to the entire svg, obviously. I have read about clipping/masking but am not exactly sure what it involves or how to proceed.

If needed, I can insert the relevant CSS for the class names however I don't think its relevant as it is mostly sizing, positioning, etc.

My apologies if I have missed something or am being dumb - I'm not great with this sort of thing!

Any help would be much appreciated.